# Is there a handy way to use Bicep modules in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I am setting up my Azure DevOps pipeline (an Azure CLI task) with the intention of deploying a resource group and several resources within it. So far I have been able to deploy and validate from my local pc with no issues however when I configure my pipeline in DevOps I get the following error message:

C:\devops_work\11\s\main_v2.bicep(55,29) : Error BCP091: An error occurred reading file. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\devops_work\11\isv-bicep\storage_account.bicep'.

For context, 'main_v2.bicep' is my "main file" where the modules are called, in this case, "storage_account.bicep"
The same error occurs for all other modules. A couple of details regarding my pipeline:

1. I am using my own agent pool
2. My code sits in an Azure Repository
3. I have tried checking 'Checkout submodules' (Any nested submodules within)
4. The files all sit at the root level of the repository
5. My pipeline is not a YAML pipeline

Any help or insight into this is duly appreciated

Comment: So you re using classic pipeline (Releases tab) ? you said all the files are at the root of the folder ? but it looks like the modules are in an `isv-bicep` folder ?

Comment: That’s the name of my Azure DevOps repository

Comment: the path of your main.bicep and modules dont match from what i can see

Comment: I am actually not setting any path anywhere in my pipeline as I left all the files in root. The error or output above is generated as the pipeline executes on my custom agent

Comment: These directories do not exist anywhere in my repository C:\devops_work\11\s

Comment: It's the folder where the build agent download all the files.

Comment: I see, I’ll revisit tomorrow and see if there is any way I can change or update that

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the working directory and ensure that your repository is being cloned.

```
steps:
  - checkout: self

  - powershell: |
      az deployment group create `
        -f "your-bicep-file.bicep" `
        -g "your-resource-group-name"        
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

If the pipeline is not in the same repository as your bicep files, on the checkout change self by the name of the repository alias, and complement the working directory with the path (By default it is cloned into $(Build.SourcesDirectory), but if you check out more than one repo it adds an extra directory).

```
steps:
  - checkout: <your repo alias>

  - powershell: |
      az deployment group create `
        -f "your-bicep-file.bicep" `
        -g "your-resource-group-name"        
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/<your repo alias>
```